# Random slogan generator with using javascript's switch

Tags: javascript

I have got little problem. I'm learning javascript and I wanted to create random slogan generator for my site with using `switch`.

So I created this html code

```
<body onload="rndqu()">
    <div id="head"> <a href="index.html">Mira's place<a><br>
            <h2>&#8220;<span id="quote"></span>&#8221;</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

and used this Javascript

```
var qu;
var slogan;
function rndqu(n){
    var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };  
    qu = random(1, 3);
}
switch(qu){
    case 1:
        slogan = "Here is the 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        slogan = "Here is the 2";
        break;
    case 3:
        slogan = "Woah";
        break;
    default:
        slogan = "Really?";
}
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = slogan;
```

I don't get it why it doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thank you! And here is jsfiddle of it http://jsfiddle.net/NX3cz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left part of the code outside the `rndqu()` function.
I forked and corrected your fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BwJ7s/

Here's the corrected JS code:

```
var qu;
var slogan;
function rndqu(n)
{
    var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };  
    qu = random(1, 3);

    switch(qu){
        case 1:
            slogan = "Here is the 1";
            break;
        case 2:
            slogan = "Here is the 2";
            break;
        case 3:
            slogan = "Woah";
            break;
        default:
            slogan = "Really?";
    }
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = slogan;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use an array instead of a switch statement for this, to make it more flexible. For example:

```
var quotesList = ["I'm a great guy!", "Not even kidding.", "Just incredible."];

var randQuote = function(quotes) {
    var choice = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    return quotes[choice];
}

document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = randQuote(quotesList);
```

This way, the size of the quote array can be changed freely without having to change any of the code.

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSEMT/)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed here http://jsfiddle.net/NX3cz/13/

```
var qu;
var slogan;
function rndqu(min, max){

    qu =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    switch(qu){
        case 1:
            slogan = "Here is the 1";
            break;
        case 2:
            slogan = "Here is the 2";
            break;
        case 3:
            slogan = "Woah";
            break;
        default:
            slogan = "Really?";
    }
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = slogan;
}

rndqu(1, 3);
```

Your code was overly complicated also notice, in jsfiddle don't add a `body onload="()"` function. Jsfiddle does that for you.

If you want to do it `onbodyload` on a real webpage wrap your code in this:

```
window.onload = (function(){
    //your code goes here
})
```

or include your script at the bottom of the html file.

Whenever possible best practice is to avoid inline javascript in your html.