# Javascript's switch mistery in my code

Tags: javascript

I have made Javascript random slogan generator for my testing site and it's somehow bugged and I don't really know why.

```
<body onload="rndqu()">
    <div id="head"> <a href="index.html">Mira's place<a><br>
            <h2>&#8220;<span id="quote"></span>&#8221;</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the Javascript

```
var qu;
var slogan;
function rndqu(n){
    var random = function(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    };  
    qu = random(1, 7);
    switch(qu){
        case 1:
            slogan = "This text is random generated. Woohooo... :P";
            break;
        case 2:
            slogan = "Mira is creating huge game named Rock Paper.";
            break;
        case 3:
            slogan = "I will add discussion on my site!";
            break;
        case 4:
            slogan = "Everyone loves Koding.";
            return;
        case 5:
            slogan = "Mira is potato. :(";
            return;
        case 6:
            slogan = "I'm learning Javascript, this slogan is made in Javascript!";
            return;
        case 7:
            slogan = "There is actually over 9000 slogans!";
            return;
        default:
            slogan = "Is it possible to get default?";
    }
    document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = slogan;
}
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work. I tried Google Chrome and it's console and used this command `rndqu(); console.log(qu);` to debug it. But I failed. I don't see any bug in the code.

When:

`qu = 1` the slogan works right.

`qu = 2` the slogan works right.

`qu = 3` the slogan works right.

`qu = 4` the slogan doesn't change.

`qu = 5` the slogan doesn't change.

`qu = 6` the slogan doesn't change.

`qu = 7` the slogan doesn't change.

It's total mistery for me why it doesn't work.

**EDIT: I'M BLIND DUMB. I'M BLIND DUMB!!!**

Comment: This is why you should have used my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709296/random-slogan-generator-with-using-javascripts-switch/15709361 in the first place! ;)

Comment: Here's an ideea: why don't you store the slogans in an array and then retrieve the slogan based on a random index? `var slogans = ['slogan 1', 'slogan 2', 'slogan 3']; var slogan = slogans[Math.floor(Math.random() * slogans.length)];`

Comment: I will do it, but I was learning switch so I wanted to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because in the cases that don't work you are using `return;` instead of `break;` and so you are exiting the function and not reaching the part where you store the result.

Comment: Thank you, I'm blind dumb! :D

Answer (score 2):

You have return instead of breaks since case number 4
Easy to fix :-)

Answer (score 2):

you've `return;` instead of `break;` in cases 4, 5, 6, and 7